# QGIS2WEB plugin leaflet option won't work

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

Using the [airports](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html) tutorial I can export as openlayers and works fine. When i attempt to use leaflet export it causes the QGIS to become unresponsive and my system to run out of memory. When i look in the folder it has compiled a lot of the code and files. It seems to be hanging whilst trying to write the shapefile data to JSON as the below photo. Is this a known issue. I need a leaflet version as ultimately i want to use omnivore to pull data onto a map from a web hosted csv.

[image] .

EDIT: It also won't display the Leaflet map in the preview pane

I'm working on Mac OS 10.11.6 with the latest version of the plugin on QGIS:

Version | 2.18.2 | QGIS code branch | Release 2.18
-- | -- | -- | --
Compiled against Qt | 4.8.6 | Running against Qt | 4.8.6
Compiled against GDAL/OGR | 2.1.2 | Running against GDAL/OGR | 2.1.2
Compiled against GEOS | 3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 | Running against GEOS | 3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246
PostgreSQL Client Version | 9.4.9 | SpatiaLite Version | 4.3.0a
QWT Version | 6.1.3 | PROJ.4 Version | 492
QScintilla2 Version | 2.9.1 |   |

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, if simplify the options it exports as leaflet. For me this meant only exporting the parameters as below image (i also deleted the wikipedia field in the original data) ;
[image]

Changing or enabling any other options results in the same problem as above. This extends to changing the marker type from the default.